# How to concatenate the non-zero column names in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

My table "tbl" have integer columns A, B, C.

For each row I'd like to print only the non-zero columns, concatenated in a single string.

I can do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE A>0 "A" ELSE "" END, 
              CASE B>0 "B" ELSE "" END,
              CASE C>0 "C" ELSE "" END)
FROM tbl
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(INCIDATE(A), INDICATE(B), INDICATE(C)) 
FROM tbl
```

Where INDICATE is a function that I will define which receives a column name col and implements

```
    INDICATE(col) := CASE col>0 col.name ELSE "" END
```

How can I do that in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this example:

```
SELECT concat (a,b,c)
from 

(
select case  when A >0 then 'A' else '' end as A,
   case  when B >0 then 'B' else '' end as B,
   case  when C >0 then 'C' else '' end as C
FROM  (VALUES (2,2,2 ), (1,2,3 ),(0,0,1 )) AS t (A, B,C) -- values is tbl
) as data
```